# TypeError: e is not defined - when trying to use JQuery each to step through images within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to select all "img" tags within "#gallery" and then retrieve the "src" attribute of each of them in turn, but cannot get it to work.

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <p><img src="/userfiles/image/medium/gallery1.jpg" alt=""></p>
    <p><img src="/userfiles/image/medium/gallery2.jpg" alt=""></p>
    <p><img src="/userfiles/image/medium/gallery3.jpg" alt=""></p>
    <p><img src="/userfiles/image/medium/gallery4.jpg" alt=""></p>
</div>
```

and my JQuery code is:

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery img').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr(src);
        console.log(src);
    });
});
```

I am getting the error "TypeError: e is not defined". Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `e is not defined` really? You don't have any `e` there. `src is not defined`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TypeError: e is not defined` seems so be somewhere else. I can't find `e` in your posted code.

But, the error in your code is this. No quotes `"src"`

```
var src = $(this).attr("src");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a [`look here`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1), it is expecting a string value for the attribute

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery img').each(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        console.log(src);
    });
});
```

This [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/LmYw7/) works for me, I removed the full image path, run in chrome to see the console output...

Comment: @Krishna, nor me?!  I haven't tested it, but I'm sure the single quotes work.

Comment: I'm also not sure why it was downvoted. It wasn't me that did so. Someone has downvoted my question also. Thanks for the answer.